# Send push notification using stomp in php

Tags: php, push-notification, activemq-classic, stomp

Recently I am interested in try push notification to mobile device using stomp in php. But I don't know how to use and what parameters are to be set.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something ? done some search ?
here some examples to start digging .

You can work with websockets like this
https://github.com/apache/activemq/tree/master/activemq-web-demo/src/main/webapp/websocket

https://github.com/jmesnil/stomp-websocket/blob/master/example/chat/index.html

http://activemq.apache.org/websockets.html

There are many libs and examples https://github.com/krukow/stomple/blob/master/example/transactional-chat.html

Comment: Yes... i have google for this..But every section is about javascript and for website..But i want to send notification for webservice.,,

Comment: you said : **I am interested in try push notification to mobile device using stomp in php** what you want is not clear, can you explain in depth what you want to do and what about webservice...